# Select All graphs from Apache Age

Tags: apache-age

How do I choose all of the graphs in Apache Age?

I am encountering difficulty in selecting all of the graphs in Apache AGE. I have attempted to do so but have been unsuccessful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a table in the ag_catalog namespace that keeps track of all the graphs. You can select it with the following command:

```
SELECT * FROM ag_catalog.ag_graph;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have already **set the search path** by using:

```
SET search_path = ag_catalog, "$user", public;
```

You can select all graphs in the Database by using:

```
SELECT * FROM ag_graph;
```

Otherwise, if you have **not set the search path**. You can select all graphs in the Database by using:

```
SELECT * FROM ag_catalog.ag_graph;
```